# What does <//> mean in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

From the following code from a simple server using Spock:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import Web.Spock
import Web.Spock.Config

import Data.Time.Clock
import Control.Concurrent
import Network.HTTP.Types.Status
import Network.HTTP.Types.URI
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Concurrent.STM 
import qualified Data.Text as T   

app :: MyApp ()
    app =
        do get root $ redirect' "https://google.no"
           -- Store params
           get ("oauth2" <//> var) $ \path' ->
             do ...
```

The majority of the imports don't relate to the question.

Comment: What are the imports?

Comment: "Ignore most of the imports. They don't relate to the question." Uh, yes they do. `<//>` only exists because of the imports.

Comment: in ghci do `:l Main.hs`, then `:info (<//>)`

Comment: Or use [hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%3C%2F%2F%3E&scope=set%3Astackage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [**`(<//>) :: Path as Open -> Path bs ps -> Path (Append as bs) ps`** function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Spock-0.13.0.0/docs/Web-Spock.html#v:-60--47--47--62-). As the documentation says:

> Combine two path components

In the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/agrafix/Spock/blob/master/Spock-api/src/Web/Spock/Api.hs#L22), we see that it is implemented as:

> ```
> (<//>) :: Path as 'Open -> Path bs ps -> Path (Append as bs) ps
> (<//>) = (</>)
> ```

This `(</>)` function originates from the [**`(</>) ::  Path as Open -> Path bs ps -> Path (Append as bs) ps`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reroute-0.5.0.0/docs/Web-Routing-Combinators.html#v:-60--47--62-) in the [**`reroute`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reroute) package. It is [implemented as [GitHub]](https://github.com/agrafix/Spock/blob/master/reroute/src/Web/Routing/Combinators.hs#L55):

> ```
> (</>) :: Path as 'Open -> Path bs ps2 -> Path (Append as bs) ps2
> (</>) Empty xs = xs
> (</>) (StaticCons pathPiece xs) ys = StaticCons pathPiece (xs </> ys)
> (</>) (VarCons xs) ys = VarCons (xs </> ys)
> ```

It thus basically appends some path pieces together. You can here see this as some sort of linked list. A string literal (like `"oauth2"`) can, with the `OverloadedStrings` be converted into a `Path` since it is an [instance of the `IsString` class [GitHub]](https://github.com/agrafix/Spock/blob/master/reroute/src/Web/Routing/Combinators.hs#L44):

> ```
> instance (a ~ '[], pathState ~ 'Open) => IsString (Path a pathState) where
>     fromString = static
> ```

It will generate a `StaticCons` with each time a piece of the path (well since `"oauth2"` does not contain any slashes, it will just have one block):

> ```
> static :: String -> Path '[] 'Open
> static s =
>   let pieces = filter (not . T.null) $ T.splitOn "/" $ T.pack s
>   in foldr StaticCons Empty pieces
> ```